# Change font family in interaction plot in R

Tags: r, plot, fonts, ggplot2

I am using `sjPlot` - a package that builds off `ggplot2` which I am new to - and I am trying to change the font family to Times New Roman. Using the example code:

```
require(sjPlot); require(effects)
fit <- lm(weight ~ Diet * Time, data = ChickWeight)
sjp.int(fit, type = "eff")
```

However, when I try to add an argument such as:

```
theme(text = element_text(size = 14, family = "Times New Roman"))
```

It doesn't work; nor does it when I try to enter similar code in `sjp.setTheme()`. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sjp.SetTheme doesn't allow you to specify font family (you'll find it to be missing from the arg list). I wasn't up for trudging through [all of this code](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/blob/master/R/sjPlotSetTheme.R) to figure out how to alter that function to give a font family spec, but I was able to alter the font family through theme_set:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(effects)
library(ggplot2)
data("ChickWeight")
fit <- lm(weight ~ Diet * Time, data = ChickWeight)

theme_set(theme_bw(base_family = 'AR BERKLEY'))
sjp.int(fit, type = "eff")
```

[image]

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_family = "Times New Roman"))
sjp.int(fit, type = "eff")
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I first installed the package install.packages("sjPlot") and then load the package library("sjPlot") then I got the error  Error in library(sjPlot) : there is no package called ‘sjPlot’
How can I then change the font type to times new roman in an effect plot using effects package?